# Images as labels - resizing problem

Tags: graphics, visualization, labeling, charts

I'd like to label a pie chart with images, ideally resized to fit inside the sectors. The problem is I can't seem to control the size of the imported images. Here's an MWE with no attempt at resizing, pie chart image size of 1000;

```
a = Import["strawman.png"];
 a2 = RemoveBackground[a];
 b = Import["cherry.png"];
b2 = RemoveBackground[b];
c = Import["burden.png"];
c2 = RemoveBackground[c];
d = Import["gradhat.png"];
d2 = RemoveBackground[d];
PieChart[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 2}, 
 ChartLabels -> {a2, b2, "blank", c2, "blank2", d2}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

This results in an image like this; [image]

I initially thought I could just resize these images, but the problem is that simply reduces the quality and not the size- it seems ImageSize is overwriting everything. For example, if I try and make the scarecrow resized to 50 pixels with

```
  a2 = ImageResize[a2,50]
```

all this does is severely pix-elate the scarecrow element as below, with no impact on size: [image]

Is there a clever way around this? I've tried Inset and Epilog and had no obvious joy with them either.

Comment: try `Magnify`, e.g.,  `Magnify[a2,.2]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane) instead of [`ImageResize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResize):. For example:

```
a1 = Pane[ExampleData[{"TestImage","Lena"}], 30];
a2 = Pane[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Aerial"}], 40];

PieChart[
    ConstantArray[1, 15],
    SectorOrigin->{Automatic,2},
    ChartLabels -> {a1,"blank",a2,"blank2"}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect, cheers!

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to using images as labels we can use them as `Texture` for sectors with a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ClearAll[cedF]
cedF[opt_: "Fill"] := Module[{cedf = If[Head[#3[[1]]] === Image, 
  System`BarFunctionDump`TextureRadius[#, #2, "Placement" -> opt] /. 
     _Texture :> Texture[#3[[1]]]&,
  ChartElementDataFunction["Sector"][##] &]}, cedf[##]] &
```

**Examples:**

```
textures = Rasterize @ Thumbnail[#, Small] & /@ 
  ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Lena", "Apples", "Mandrill", "Flower"};
```

Attach textures to input data as metadata:

```
data = Thread[ConstantArray[1, 6] -> Join[textures, {Red, Blue} ]];
```

With default value of the argument ("Fill") a picture is cropped to the shape of  the associated sector:

```
PieChart[data, SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, ChartElementFunction -> cedF[]]
```

[image]

With `ChartElementFunction -> cedF["StretchToFill"]`:

[image]

and with `ChartElementFunction -> cedF["Tile"]`:

[image]